# How to display one specific taxonomy category desciption

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I need to display one specific taxonomy category description with its id.Tried with this code

```
$term_id = 9;
$taxonomy_name = 'service-item-tax';
$term = get_term_by('id', $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
echo $term->description;
```

But it didnt work.Help me to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do the following:

```
echo term_description('TERM_ID','TAXONOMY_SLUG');
```